# Can you recommend a .cvsignore file for a Visual C#.NET solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, cvs

I've developed a Visual C#.NET 2008 Express Edition solution containing three projects. I am cleaning it up to commit it into a CVS repository.

There are several files that are created during the build process that are not necessary to be placed in the repository since they will be regenerated automatically.

The question: Can anyone suggest a list of patterns to be placed into a .cvsignore file so that these generated files and folders are ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically these are the only things that you *have* to commit:

- .sln files
- .cs files
- .csproj files
- .config files
- External DLLs and corresponding XML/config files that you are referencing
- other non-generated files that your application uses

All the rest are to be ignored, including:

- .suo files
- .csproj.user files
- /bin folder and contents
- /obj folder and contents
- practically everything else

Answer (score 2):

Thanks!  This is what I have created:

```
bin
obj
*.cache
*.suo
*.csproj.user
```